# Preference activity with sliding menu

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, slidingmenu

I'm trying to put a preference activity in the behind content of a sliding menu.

Here is my main_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#202222"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<PreferenceScreen
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/general" >
    <Preference android:title="@string/news" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/sport" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/business" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/economy" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/news" >
    <Preference android:title="@string/international" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/national"/>
    <Preference android:title="@string/local" />
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is what I do in my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(120);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And when I run the application it crashes and says "Failed to inflate. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 : Error inflating class PreferenceScreen

I also have this exception : com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup in main_menu.xml

I wanna do something like that : [image example](http://cyrilmottier.com/media/2012/05/the-making-of-prixing-fly-in-app-menu-part-1/app_menu_large.png)

Comment: Your screen shot is obviously not using a built-in PreferenceActivity. They put a random view (maybe an ExpandableListView in this case) that mimic the same behavior).